# Mostrar un div con vue js

Tags: html, vue.js

quiero mostrar un div que tengo oculto y con un `<a href="">` lo quiero mostrar, busque en la documentación pero no entendi mucho y no he podido.

aqui tengo el la etiqueta :
`<a href="" class="ml-4" @click.prevent="showHide">`

esta es la que quiero mostrar

`<div v-show="false" v-model="forgetPassword">  show   </div>`

Aqui esta el codigo Vue:

> 

```
new Vue({
    el: '#formLogin', 
    data : {
        forgetPassword : ''
    },
    methods: {
        showHide: function (){
            //console.log('hello');
            this.forgetPassword = true;

        }
    }
})
```

Me gustaria saber como guardar un true o false, en forgetPassword ya que me lo muestra como vacío cuando lo muestro por consola.
Quedo atento a comentarios.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tienes que declarar una variable que le indicara al div si hacerse visible o no.
Luego con la función showHide actualizas esta variable.

Este es un ejemplo funcional:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#formLogin',
  data: {
   show: true
  },
  methods: {
   showHide: function(){
     this.show = !this.show;
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>

<div id="formLogin">
<a href="" class="ml-4" @click.prevent="showHide">click</a>

<div v-show="show">  show   </div>

</div>
```